# Function that flows from y=a in a curve to y=x

Tags: functions

I'm searching for a function that looks approximately like the red line in this sketch:
[image: plotted function]
The function should start horizontally like y=a and flow in a curve to a diagonal line like y=x. I need to give the value a of course but I'm not sure what other values i will need.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a hyperbola

Comment: Yes. Specifically, $y = \sqrt{x^2+a^2}$.

Comment: Convergence seems a bit fast for a hyperbola; I would try $y=x+ae^{-kx}$ and pick $k$ that fits best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gregory Grant mentioned, this question looks like part of a hyperbola. In particular, you can use the equation
$$\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1,\hspace{10mm}x,y\ge0$$

to get a similar looking function with $y$-intercept at $(0,a)$ and the equation of the line in your picture as $$y=\frac{a}{b}x$$

[Here's what that looks like with $a=b=1$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2-x%5E2%3D1%2Cx>%3D0%2Cy>%3D0)

Answer (score 0):

Try $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$, it is half of the "reversed" unit hyperbola.